# SecurityError: Error #2152: Full screen mode is not allowed.

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fullscreen

I have one flash player , which have full-screen functionality . which is not working in FF and MAC Chrome . and throws an error as below.

```
SecurityError: Error #2152: Full screen mode is not allowed.
    at flash.display::Stage/set displayState()
    at com.IQMediaCorp.core::IQMediaCorpPlayer/ToggleFullScreen()
```

I have googled about the issue and already verified some points below

1. my player have `allowfullscreen = true` in html object / encode
   element.
2. the methid `ToggleFullScreen` is an mouse click event

below is code for `ToggleFullScreen` method

```
public function ToggleFullScreen(e:MouseEvent)
        {

                if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE)
                {
                    bKnob.alpha=0;
                    bigScreen=true;                 
                    stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
                }
                else
                {
                    bigScreen=false;
                    stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
                    bKnob.alpha=0;

                }
        }
```

i don't get the reason why it is not working. can anybody help??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the reason this is happening is you cannot have `StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE` in Flash less than version 11.3

Try `StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN` instead!

So check which version of flash you are building for here is an exerpt from the [Adobe docs on displayState](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageDisplayState.html)

Runtime Versions:   Flash Player 11.3, AIR 1.0, Flash Lite 4

Specifies that the Stage is in full-screen mode with keyboard interactivity enabled. As of Flash Player 11.3, this capability is supported in both AIR applications and browser-based applications.

Comment: hi @Neil, for your reply... i have flash player 11.3 installed in my browser , then also it is not working , anyways... it worked for `StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN` , and i don't need keyboard interactivity , so m happy with this at now. thanks again :)